# inserting a modbus value in postgres databse using c languge

Tags: c, postgresql

How to insert a variable in postgresql database while using c language? I am trying to insert a variable using   “:”  but it’s not working

```
float g=1.23;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PGconn *conn = PQconnectdb("user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres");
    if (PQstatus(conn) == CONNECTION_BAD) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s\n",
        PQerrorMessage(conn));

        PQfinish(conn);
        exit(1);
    }
    PGresult *res = PQexec(conn, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS modbus_value");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
        do_exit(conn, res);
    }
    PQclear(res);

    res = PQexec(conn, "insert into modbus_value(id,temp) values(1,:g)");

    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK) {
        do_exit(conn, res);
    }
    PQclear(res);
    PQexit(conn);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You can always create a query string, e.g. `sprintf(szSQL, "insert into modbus_value(id,temp) values(1,%f)", g);`

Comment: regarding; `float g=1.23;`  This is declaring a `double` variable, then trying to force it into a `float` variable.  Suggest: `float g=1.23f;`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `PQexec`, use [`PQexecParams`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-MAIN), and use `$1` rather than `:g`.

For example:

```
 char value[10];
 snprintf(value, 10, "%f", g);

 res = PQexecParams(conn,
                    "insert into modbus_value(id,temp) values(1,$1)",
                    1
                    NULL,
                    &value,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    0);
```

Comment: An example would be useful.

Comment: Useful example, although the original code was trying to insert a floating point value (`float g = 1.23;`), not an integer.

Comment: i wrote as you advised  in pi 3 and  after compiled ,it shows warning "undefined reference PQexecParams"

Comment: What is pi 3? Anyway, if the library contains `PQexec`, it should also contain `PQexecParams`. Are you linking with `-lpq`?

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEAEAbm.o: in function `main':
connection.c:(.text+0x340): undefined reference to `PGexecParamas'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You made a spelling error. There is no connection between that function and central America.

Answer (score -1):

Postgres won't know that `g` in the SQL command is supposed to be the value of a C variable. It doesn't know anything about C variables. You will need to construct the SQL command in an array of `char` using `sprintf` and pass that to `PGexec`.

For example:

```
    char pgcmd[100];

    sprintf(pgcmd, "insert into modbus_value(id,temp) values(1,%g)", g);
    res = PQexec(conn, pgcmd);
```

Comment: If this were. not a numeric value, you would risk SQL injection.

Comment: char pgcmd[100];

   PGexec( sprintf(pgcmd, "insert into modbus_value(id,temp) values(1,%g)", g));
    res = PQexec(conn, pgcmd);

Comment: above code as i applied ,but its not working kindly suggest.

Comment: @pankajdusane Why are you calling `sprintf` inside `PGexec`? (Or is that a typo?).

Comment: After compiled a code below error msg is show,
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEAEAbm.o: in function `main':
connection.c:(.text+0x340): undefined reference to `PGexecParamas'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
when i tried to run a code error shows sudo./conn command not found.